# Pulling info from JSON by Key value

Tags: python, json, indexing, key

I'm working with an API that sends JSON files in the following structure (and I'm trying to use the API in Python):

```
{
    "inventory": [
        {
            "ID": 10,
            "name": "Potion",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "ID": 15,
            "name": "Ether",
            "quantity": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

But with hundreds of items.

What I'm trying to do is find the quantity of a particular item, based on its unique 'ID' key's value. So I might be looking for the amount of Potions I have based on the ID '10', and I'm stumped as to how to do that.

I tried:

```py
for key, value in inventory_data.items():
   if key["ID"] == 10:
      potion_index = index
```

To try to pull the index so I could then write a code snippet to pull by the index of where Potion falls in the inventory, but that didn't work.

Also - the list and order of the inventory changes, so I can't find the index just once and be good, I'd need to search each time.

Comment: And what is the question? Do you need to remove dictionary with `ID == 10` from the list? I recommend to convert the inventory list to dictionary, to make the searching by ID easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the quantity of item with `ID == 10` or how you can remove the item (using list-comprehension):

```py
dct = {
    "inventory": [
        {"ID": 10, "name": "Potion", "quantity": 20},
        {"ID": 15, "name": "Ether", "quantity": 12},
    ]
}

# to get the quantity of item with 'ID' == 10:
qnt = next(d["quantity"] for d in dct["inventory"] if d["ID"] == 10)
print(qnt)
```

Prints:

```
20
```

---

To remove dict with `'ID' == 10`, use list-comprehension:

```
dct["inventory"] = [d for d in dct["inventory"] if d["ID"] != 10]
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```
{"inventory": [{"ID": 15, "name": "Ether", "quantity": 12}]}
```

---

But I recommend to convert the inventory from list to dictionary:

```py
# convert the inventory to dictionary:
dct["inventory"] = {d["ID"]: d for d in dct["inventory"]}

# searching for item with ID == 10 is now key lookup:
print(dct["inventory"][10]["quantity"])
```

Prints:

```
20
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot for your help.